# Not sure why integral of $\sqrt{a^2-x^2}$ result includes absolute value

Tags: integration

I worked out the integral of $\sqrt{a^2-x^2}dx$ and found it to be $\frac{x\sqrt{a^2-x^2}+a^2arcsin(\frac{x}a)}2 + C$ via the trig sub $x=asin(\theta)$

However, [integral-calculator.com](https://www.integral-calculator.com/) returns the result shown below:

[image]

This agrees with my answer up until the last step where an absolute value is introduced and for some reason $a^2-x^2$ is factorised. Please can anyone explain why this is done and why my answer is incorrect?

Comment: Implicit in the problem statement is $a\ge 0$.

Comment: The two forms are different, but neither one is correct. The antiderivative should be an even function of $a$, so both forms are correct for $a > 0$ and incorrect for $a < 0$. If $a \in \mathbb R$ and $-|a| < x < |a|$, then $\sqrt {a^2 \cos^2 \theta} = |a| \cos \theta$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your answer is correct. the other one is just factorized out by $ a $.

The difference  comes from the fact that

$$\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{a^2}}=$$

$$\sqrt{\frac{a^2-x^2}{a^2}}=$$

$$\frac{\sqrt{(a+x)(a-x)}}{\sqrt{a^2}}=$$

$$\frac{\sqrt{-(x-a)(x+a)}}{|a|}$$

because
$$\sqrt{a^2}=|a|$$

Comment: Thanks that makes sense.